# Trying to deploy a shiny app that uses python modules

Tags: python, shiny, reticulate

I'm currently working on a Shiny app that integrates Python code for some of its functionalities. I've used the `reticulate` package to manage the interaction between R and Python. Locally, everything works as expected, but I'm facing challenges deploying the app to `shinyapps.io`, particularly with setting up the Python environment correctly on the platform. I've been at this for days and I am losing my mind. I keep getting this error:

```
Error in stop_no_virtualenv_starter(version = version, python = python) : Suitable Python installation for creating a venv not found.
Requested Python: python3
Please install Python with one of following methods:

- https://github.com/rstudio/python-builds/
- reticulate::install_python(version = '\<version\>')
```

Here's the context:

My app relies on the `openai` Python package, among others, specified in a `requirements.txt` file.

Locally, I create a virtual environment (`openai-env`). and install the required packages using `reticulate` functions: `virtualenv_create`, `virtualenv_install`, and `use_virtualenv`. I then source a Python script (Python_Script.py) that utilizes these packages.

The relevant portion of my R code looks something like this:

```
 `library(reticulate)
  virtualenv_create("openai-env", python = "python3")
  virtualenv_install("openai-env", packages = c("openai"))
  use_virtualenv("openai-env", required = TRUE)
  source_python("Python_Script.py")     `
```

My .R profile looks like this:

```
`# This file configures the virtualenv and Python paths differently depending on
     # the environment the app is running in (local vs remote server).

     # Edit this name if desired when starting a new app
     VIRTUALENV_NAME = 'openai-env'


      # ------------------------- Settings (Edit local settings to match your system) ---------     ----------------- #

      if (Sys.info()[['user']] == 'shiny'){
  
     # Running on shinyapps.io
      Sys.setenv(PYTHON_PATH = 'python3')
      Sys.setenv(VIRTUALENV_NAME = VIRTUALENV_NAME) # Installs into default shiny virtualenvs     dir
      Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = paste0('/home/shiny/.virtualenvs/', VIRTUALENV_NAME, '/bin/python'))
  
} else if (Sys.info()[['user']] == 'rstudio-connect'){
  
  # Running on remote server
  Sys.setenv(PYTHON_PATH = '/opt/python/3.7.7/bin/python3')
  Sys.setenv(VIRTUALENV_NAME = paste0(VIRTUALENV_NAME, '/')) # include '/' => installs into rstudio-connect/apps/
  Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = paste0(VIRTUALENV_NAME, '/bin/python'))
  
} else {
  
  # Running locally
  options(shiny.port = 7450)
  Sys.setenv(PYTHON_PATH = 'python3')
  Sys.setenv(VIRTUALENV_NAME = VIRTUALENV_NAME) # exclude '/' => installs into ~/.virtualenvs/
  # RETICULATE_PYTHON is not required locally, RStudio infers it based on the ~/.virtualenvs path
}``
```